# How to Create PHP Form with Collapsible Sections?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a multi-part form that will use PHP for the server side database insertion.  The form needs to be validated, and I intend to use JQuery Validate to display one icon if the section validates, and another if the section does not.

I'm aware of the use of collapsible panels or DIVs.  However, I need to use this same collapsible effect inside my form.  How can this be achieved either via JQuery or another client side library?

Thanks much!!

Comment: Sounds like your question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're at the point to decide what framework to use you may check the [collapsible forms by ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/dynamic.html) framework, it may give you some initial idea.

**EDIT**

@SidC: OK, if you're going with JQuery, you'll better not to mess up with Ext. Don't see much pain to implement if from zero using [JQuery::Accordion](http://JQuery::Accordion) plugin plus the [JQuery::DIALOG](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). And check this feed

[JQuery Accordion: how to embedded it into a dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792430/jquery-accordion-how-to-embedded-it-into-a-dialog-box)

Comment: The app uses JQuery heavily.  Is it a major pain to bring in ExtJS as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide inside a form just as easily as outside.

```
object.style.display = "none"
```

is the JS.

Wrap what you're showing and hiding in a div and go to it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is correct, and not only because we share the same name.

Wrap your HTML form in a div, and then use this:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

It's animated too ;)

Comment: I need to collapse many form sections. Can animatedcollapse be used within a form tag?  I didn't think DIV tags were allowed inside a form?

Comment: @SidC - put your entire form inside a div tag, and then collapse the div